# Bringing first activity on top of back stack

Tags: java, android

I have two applications with one activity in each of them. Application A and application B. Application A has its activity's launch type as SingleTask. Both Activities have buttons calling each other. What I want is that when I launch activity A from activity B's button which is in turn launched from activity A's button, and then when I press back button activity B should come to foreground. But instead it is going back to launcher. I have attached code for reference.

Application A MainActivity:-

```
package com.example.appa;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i =new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.example.appb", "com.example.appb.MainActivity");
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Application A Manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Application B MainActivity:

```
package com.example.appb;

import com.example.appb.R;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i =new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.example.appa", "com.example.appa.MainActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Application B Manifest is unmodified default mainfest

As it can be seen I have already tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT but it did not help.

P.S :- I cannot change launch type of activity in application A

Thanks in advance

Comment: singleTask negates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `singleTask` launch mode is not compatible with that behavior. You can set a different launch mode each time you start an activity by setting flags, but a better approach might be to reevaluate the choice made for default launch mode.

[Tasks and back stack article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).